# lstinline loses braces when used as an argument to another command

Tags: macros, listings, braces

I'm using the `listings` package, for the Java language (which, as all C-like languages, uses braces as a block delimiter). I intend to use `\lstinline{...}` as the second argument to a command for typesetting Hoare triples.

While `\lstinline|while (...) { ... } |` typesets the braces correctly, they are removed if `\lstinline|...|` is passed as argument to any macro. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Java}

\newcommand{\hoare}[3]{\{ $#1$ \} #2 \{ $#3$ \} }
\newcommand{\true}{\mathbf{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\mathbf{false}}

\begin{document}
\hoare{\true}{\lstinline|while(true) { }|}{\false}
\end{document}
```

How do I get my braces back?

Comment: `\lstinline` is a verbatim-like command: it tries to not interpret any special character such as `%`, `#`, `{`, `}`, etc. Unfortunately, when it is passed as an argument of another command, it doesn't get to do the magic to tell TeX not to interpret those characters: your braces already acquired a special meaning. Try `\hoare{\true}{\scantokens{\lstinline|while(true) { }|}}{\false}`. Not general, but should work in this particular case.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You could quote the braces to make them visible:

```
\hoare{\true}{\lstinline|while(true) \{ \}|}{\false}
```

[image: lstinline with braces]

When directly called, `\lstinline|while(true) \{ \}|` would also print the backslash, but not here in the macro argument, because the outer macro already deals with the quoted braces.

Comment: then `\lstinline` makes no sense

Comment: @Herbert `\lstinline` is still useful for pretty-printing the code snippets, such as regarding listings font settings, language style such as syntax emphasizing etc. Even if you have to quote.

Comment: in general yes, but not in this special case